# How to copy/insert multiple rows of data to implement many to many relationship in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have the following tables in Postgres: questions, responses and question_response. There is a many to many relationship between questions and responses.

## questions.sql

```
CREATE TABLE questions( 
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    question VARCHAR(255)
);
```

## respones.sql

```
CREATE TABLE responses( 
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    response VARCHAR(255)
);
```

## question_respone.sql #

```
CREATE TABLE question_response(
    question_id bigint REFERENCES questions ON DELETE CASCADE,
    response_id bigint REFERENCES responses ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY ( question_id, response_id)
);
```

I have the following data in questions table

```
id | question
 1   Rate the effectiveness of the program?
 2   Rate the ease of learning?
 3   Rate the duration ?
 .....
// there are a list of 20 questions
```

and in responses table

```
id | response
 100   Poor
 200   Average
 300   Good
 400   Excellent
```

How do I write a query of function in Postgres to insert the following data in question_response table.

```
question_id | response_id

         1   100
         1   200
         1   300
         1   400
         2   100
         2   200
         2   300
         2   400
         3   100
         3   200
         3   300
         3   400
         4   100
         4   200
         4   300
         4   400
        ......... etc for all 20 questions
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert  into question_response
select  q.id
,       r.id
from    responses r
cross join
        questions q
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7bc2a/3/0)

Comment: @Andomar  thanks for the help. I am trying to extract the questions and responses by referencing their ids in the question_response table but I the following error. Not sure what If I am missing something here.

`select q1.question, r1.response from questions q1,  responses r1, question_reponse qr where q1.id = qr.question_id and r1.id = qr.response_id group by q1.question;`

**ERROR:  relation "question_reponse" does not exist
LINE 1: ...on, r1.response from questions q1,  responses r1, question_r...**

Comment: The error says the relation (another name for a table) does not exist. But the relation is named `question_response` in your question... are you sure it has that name in the database?

Comment: @Andomar I think I got it. There was a typo in the query. Sorry about that